# ”_grokparsefailure” even though the grok pattern works

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse different logs lines from two different type of file : slave and master. I did test my pattern in the Grok Dubugger and it is working fine but tags field in kibana is _grokparsefailure.

Here is my config file

```
input {
    file { 
        type => "slave"
        path => "/home/mathis/Documents/**/intranet*.log"
        exclude =>"*8402.log"
        sincedb_path => '/dev/null'
        start_position => beginning
    }
    file { 
        type => "master"
        path => "/home/mathis/Documents/**/intranet*8402.log"
        sincedb_path => '/dev/null'
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "slave" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => ["\[%{DATESTAMP:eventtime}\] \- %{USERNAME:user} \- %{IPV4:clientip} \- %{NUMBER} \- %{WORD} %{NUMBER:exectime} %{WORD} %{NUMBER:time} %{GREEDYDATA:data} %{NUMBER:waittime}","\[%{DATESTAMP:eventtime}\] \- Process status database sync \- %{WORD}\.%{WORD}\.%{WORD}\:%{NUMBER:slavenumb}\(\#%{NUMBER}\) \(load %{NUMBER:nbutilisateur} grace period 5 minutes\) %{GREEDYDATA}"] }
            remove_field => "message"
        }
    date {
                match => [ "eventtime", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
    }
    if [type] == "master" {
        grok {
                match => {"message" => ["%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}(?<starttime>((?!<[0-9])%{HOUR}:)?%{MINUTE}(?::%{SECOND})(?![0-9]))"]}
                remove_field => "message"
        }
            date {
                match => [ "starttime", "HH:mm:ss","mm:ss" ]
            }
    }
        
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "logstash-local3-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Here are the 3 logs lines that I want to parse :
(they are in the order of groks in my conf file)

```
[24/06/2020 21:57:29.548] - Process status database sync - us1salx08167.corpnet2.com:8100(#53738) (load 0 grace period 5 minutes) : current date 2020/06/24 21:57:29 update date 2020/06/24 21:55:44 old state OK new state OK

[29/05/2020 07:41:51.354] - ih912865 - 10.104.149.128 - 93 - Transaction 7635 COMPLETED 318 ms wait time 3183 ms

   31730  31626  464 10970020     52:25 /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64/opx2-intranet.exe -I /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64/opx2-intranet.dxl -H /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64 -L /plw/PLW_PROD/modules/preload-intranet.ini -- plw-sysconsole -port 8400 -logdir /plw/PLW_PROD/httpdocs/admin/log/ -slaves 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know if you've already resolved this -- but below is something you could use.

N.B. I added a couple of extra fields, but you can easily remove those [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field].

When trying the expressions you provided, one of them actually failed in the grok debugger, so I just took it upon myself to rewrite them all from scratch while still maintaining variable names.

I noticed there was a lot of data that you simply didn't glean. If you want more captured, let me know.

**Line 1:**

```
    [24/06/2020 21:57:29.548] - Process status database sync - us1salx08167.corpnet2.com:8100(#53738) (load 0 grace period 5 minutes) : current date 2020/06/24 21:57:29 update date 2020/06/24 21:55:44 old state OK new state OK
```

**Pattern 1:**

```
    \[(?<eventtime>%{DATESTAMP})\] - Process status database sync - (?<host>%{HOSTNAME}):(?<slavenumber>%{NUMBER})(?<zz>\(#[\d]+\)) \(load (?<nbutilisateur>%{NUMBER}) grace period 5 minutes\)%{GREEDYDATA}
```

**Line 2:**

```
    [29/05/2020 07:41:51.354] - ih912865 - 10.104.149.128 - 93 - Transaction 7635 COMPLETED 318 ms wait time 3183 ms
```

**Pattern 2:**

```
    \[(?<eventtime>%{DATESTAMP})\] - (?<user>%{USER}) - (?<clientip>%{IPV4}) - %{NUMBER} - %{WORD} (?<exectime>%{NUMBER}) %{WORD} (?<ctime>%{NUMBER}) (?<ctimeunits>%{WORD}) wait time (?<waittime>%{NUMBER}) (?<waittimeunits>%{WORD})
```

**Line 3:**

```
       31730  31626  464 10970020     52:25 /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64/opx2-intranet.exe -I /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64/opx2-intranet.dxl -H /plw/modules/bin/Lx86_64 -L /plw/PLW_PROD/modules/preload-intranet.ini -- plw-sysconsole -port 8400 -logdir /plw/PLW_PROD/httpdocs/admin/log/ -slaves 2
```

**Pattern 3:**

```
    %{GREEDYDATA}(?<starttime>(?<=[\s])([\d]+:[\d]+))%{GREEDYDATA}
```